# How to run Docker Wordpress through php-fpm on nginx?

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

Hey there I tried different things but they lead me to the nginx startpage, error 403 or error 404. I'm currently running Wordpress without php-fpm but it does not work so good so I want to change it but I only got problems while doing it.

My Wordpress Docker-compose (without db):

```
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    links:
      - wordpress-db
    depends_on:
      - wordpress-db
    image: wordpress:php7.4-fpm
    ports: 
      - 9000:9000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /media/storage/wordpress:/var/www/html
      - .secrets/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    networks:
      - wordpress
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    env_file:
      - .secrets/wordpress.env
```

My nginx compose file:

```
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    image: cptdaydreamer/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 4443:4443
    volumes:
      - /media/storage/log:/var/log/nginx
      - /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
    external_links:
      - wordpress
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    build:
      context: /media/storage/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - nextcloudpi
      - wordpress
      - matomo
      - php
```

And now the important part. My nginx configuration:

```
http {

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

  access_log off;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  
  autoindex_localtime on;
  #more_clear_headers Server;

  ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/tld.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/tld.key;
  
  gzip            on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/xml application/javascript application/json application/xml application/rss+xml image/svg+xml;
  gzip_disable    "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  
  proxy_send_timeout 180s;
  proxy_read_timeout 180s;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name tld.de cloud.tld.de www.tld.de stats.tld.de;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  
  # WordPress
  
  server {
    server_name tld.de www.tld.de ts.tld.de;
    
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress-error.log;
    
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    
    client_max_body_size 500m;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    
    root /var/www/html; 
    index index.php;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
  }
```

Errors I get are for example like this: directory index of /var/www/html is forbidden.

If I delete the `$uri/` for example I get error 404. What do I need to do to get my instance running? But I'm right that I can use my existing wordpress instance and only the way to access it changes or not?

Answer (score 0):

you are listening on ssl, but you have not provided certificates path?

do you happen to use any external ssl provider like Cloudflare? if yes, than you have to either listen on port 80 ( which is default on Cloudflare) or setup at Cloudflare to get https site, in that case you also need to provide your own certificate path.

Secondly in your `location /` block, I have this `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;`  , and few other settings

```
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
    }
    location ~ \.(php)$ {
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
      proxy_connect_timeout 3000s;
      proxy_send_timeout   3000;
      proxy_read_timeout   3000;
    }
```

`fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000` will be different, in your case it's `wordpress:9000`

Comment: I'm using a Cloudflare SSL cert thats right. I have defined it in the http part. My other containers like matomo, nextcloud and stuff work well with the config to listen on 443. So what exactly do you mean with listen on port 80? Where and what needs to listen on port 80 then? I'll add the http part to the question.

Comment: If i deleted index and root I only get Welcome to nginx!. Otherwise I get directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden which is also wrong.

Comment: I see, what is the uid of `www-data` user of directory `/var/www/html`? you can try to link to this folder  `root /usr/share/nginx/html/` which should be owned by `www-data` with uid 82

Comment: You are on the wrong path. I missed something on a tutorial and now I get to the startpage but 13: Permission denied for every image and stuff of wp-content.